# Could not find protoc-3.9.2-osx on Flutter/Android build

Tags: android, macos, flutter, gradle

I am working on a Flutter application which integrates a native package which uses Protobuff. I work on Android Studio and Mac (Apple ship).

On windows, the application builds, but since I work on MacOs I can no longer build the application. I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ‘:mypackage:generateDebugProto’.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ‘:mypackage:protobufToolsLocator_protoc’.
   > Could not find protoc-3.9.2-osx-aarch_64.exe (com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protoc/3.9.2/protoc-3.9.2-osx-aarch_64.exe

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 888ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

The build on iOS doesn't work either.

How can I resolve this error? Do you have any ideas on where the problem is coming from?

Comment: I see `jcenter.bintray.com` however that repo is EOL: https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/ and https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown You might want to expand on how you integrating protobuf/what libraries.

Comment: Thanks, may be the solution. But it's possible to use protobuf without jcenter ? How force to get it without jcenter ?

Comment: In my gradle.build, if I replace jcenter() by mavenCentral(), I have exactly the same error. (My cache have been cleared).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found a solution based on : https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7690

I have create file : `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` with :

```
protoc_platform=osx-x86_64
```

My build.gradle :

```
protobuf {
// Configure the protoc executable
protoc {
    // for apple m1, add protoc_platform=osx-x86_64 in $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties
    if (project.hasProperty('protoc_platform')) {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.2:${protoc_platform}"
    } else {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.2"
    }
}
plugins {
    javalite {
        // The codegen for lite comes as a separate artifact
        if (project.hasProperty('protoc_platform')) {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0:${protoc_platform}"
        } else {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
     }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hey Dev, it worked like a charm. Thanks for the answer. Should be accepted.

Comment: Can you please tell me the path where to add those line of code in my project. is it android build.gradle. ? if i add those line there there was another error occured

Comment: Hi, can you tell me the exact path of these files especially $HOME does that mean the android directory or the flutter directory? and which build.gradle file you have added this app folder or the root project one?

Answer (score 5):

`x86_64` works both on Intel and Apple chips

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/3.20.1/
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc-gen-javalite/3.0.0/

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

// Compatible with macOS on Apple Silicon
def archSuffix = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC) ? ':osx-x86_64' : ''

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.20.1$archSuffix"
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0$archSuffix"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's working for me for MacOs- m1 pro chip**:

I have create file : $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties with :

`protoc_platform=osx-x86_64`

And add this in your `build.gradle` (app)

```
android {
    ......

    sourceSets {
        main {
            proto {
            }
        }
    }
    .......
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibVersion"
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.2:osx-x86_64"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.1.2:osx-x86_64'
        }
        javalite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0:osx-x86_64"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
                grpc {
                    // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/build/generated"
}
```